# PgBouncer transaction mode does not support prepared-statements even with prepareThreshold=0

Tags: pgbouncer

I am using PgBouncer in "transaction" mode for connection pooling. Our code already have PreparedStatements used at multiple places. 
Even though FAQ on PgBouncer https://www.pgbouncer.org/faq.html#how-to-use-prepared-statements-with-transaction-pooling suggests to use prepareThreshold=0 to disable preparedStatements , but in reality this does not work.
Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

That's old question but I am going to answer it for reference.

Try also adding **`preparedStatementCacheQueries=0`** to your JDBC connection string.

```
e.g. jdbc:postgresql://{0}:{1}/{2}?user={3}&password={4}&prepareThreshold=0&preparedStatementCacheQueries=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PgBouncer 1.21.0 it now supports protocol level named prepared statements, so you shouldn't need to disable them in JDBC anymore. You can turn this support on by setting `max_prepared_statements` to a non-zero value in PgBouncer its config file. For details check the docs: https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#max_prepared_statements